# Example of non linear operator whose derivative is compact on a Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, nonlinear-analysis, frechet-derivative

I am looking for a non linear operator on a Hilbert space whose Frechet derivative is a compact operator? Any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps
$$
f\longmapsto \int_0^1 f^2(t) d t
$$
defined on $L^2(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Its derivative at a point $h$ is $\int_{0}^{1}2f(t)h(t) dt$ .  Am i correct?

Comment: More precisely, its derivative at point $f$ is the compact operator $A: h\mapsto \int_0^1 2 f(t) h(t) dt$

Comment: No continuous operator can be one to one from an infinite dimensional Hilbert space to a finite dimensional space. You could perhaps add new questions to the original question, or start a new thread.